# Make UITabBar Icons not resize/scale when clicked?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I want the icons in my `UITabBar` to not scale down when pressed. It's not extremely noticeable when you click the icons quickly, but when you hold for a second, you notice them scaling down.

[GIF of icons scaling when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79YxA.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized it was the image inset values I changed in the size inspector.